# google datastore how to get entities based on property value

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-datastore

I am wondering how to retrieve all the rows/entities matching property value(s) in `google cloud datastore` using `Python`. The `datastore client` `get` and `get_multi` can only return entities from key(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [Datastore Queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries) are for:

> A query retrieves [entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) from Google Cloud Datastore that meet
>   a specified set of conditions.
>
> The query operates on entities of a given [kind](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#kinds_and_identifiers); it can specify
>   [filters](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#filters) on the entities' property values, keys, and ancestors,
>   and can return zero or more entities as results. A query can also
>   specify [sort orders](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#sort_orders) to sequence the results by their property
>   values. The results include all entities that have at least one value
>   for every property named in the filters and sort orders, and whose
>   property values meet all the specified filter criteria. The query can
>   return entire entities, projected entities, or just entity keys.
>
> A typical query includes the following:
>
> - An [entity kind](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#kinds_and_identifiers) to which the query applies
> - Zero or more [filters](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#filters) based on the entities' property values, keys, and ancestors
> - Zero or more [sort orders](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#sort_orders) to sequence the results
>
> When executed, the query retrieves all entities of the given kind that
>   satisfy all of the given filters, sorted in the specified order.
>   Queries execute as read-only.